# scrapy always Starting new HTTP connection after crawl

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

After my spider has crawled all the urls,scrapy doesn't stoped,how to stop it after crawl finished?

The start url is `http://http://192.168.139.28/dvwa`.

After my spider finished,it seems the spider is always `Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28`,and I don't know how to make it stop by itself,can you help me?

Here is the output info:

```
 'retry/reason_count/504 Gateway Time-out': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 82,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 82,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 82,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 82,
 'splash/execute/request_count': 40,
 'splash/execute/response_count/200': 38,
 'splash/execute/response_count/400': 1,
 'splash/execute/response_count/504': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 6, 36, 4, 298146)}
  2018-01-10 14:37:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
  2018-01-10 14:38:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:38:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:39:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:39:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:40:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:40:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:41:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:41:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:42:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:42:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:43:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:43:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:44:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:44:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:45:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:45:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:46:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:46:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:47:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:47:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:48:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:48:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:49:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:49:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:50:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:50:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:51:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:51:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:52:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:52:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  2018-01-10 14:53:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28
  2018-01-10 14:53:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://192.168.139.28:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3041
  ...
```

I am using scrapy_splash with scrapy,and the scrapy_splash server got 504 error like [here](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#timeouts),then I try to start scrapy_splash server by `docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 3600`,but it doesn't help,scrapy is still `Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.139.28`.

My spider code is:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
os.chdir("./crawler")
cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl exp10it'.split())
```

Later when I try to use the command line:`scrapy crawl exploit`,the issue doesn't come out and scrapy just stops normaly after crawl finished,but I don't know why `cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl exp10it'.split())` does'nt stop.

Comment: Showing us a snippet of your code would be a good start.  Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updated like upon.